# httpd and mysqld used out of memory

Tags: centos, mysql, apache-httpd, out-of-memory

I choose 512mb ram for my Centos VPS with very low traffic new website .but after 2,3 hours after rebooting, i have only 24mb free memory.
when i use top command:

`2981 root      20   0 37176  10m 6440 S  0.0  2.1   0:00.15 httpd

 2983 apache    20   0 37176 5244  724 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.00 httpd

 2984 apache    20   0 37176 5228  708 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.00 httpd

 2985 apache    20   0 37176 5228  708 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.00 httpd

 2986 apache    20   0 37176 5228  708 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.00 httpd

 2987 apache    20   0 37176 5228  708 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.00 httpd

 2988 apache    20   0 37176 5228  708 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.00 httpd

 2989 apache    20   0 37176 5228  708 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.00 httpd

 2990 apache    20   0 37176 5228  708 S  0.0  1.0   0:00.00 httpd`

why httpd,mysqld,named run several times?
in htop, mysqld run several times and mysqld run this command:

`/usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/ --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log`

Alos sum of all process's usage percent about 50-60 percent , and should 250 mb my ram used not 500mb!!! 
What should i do?

Comment: upgrade your VPS to have more RAM.  Unlike a physical server, this is probably as simple as talking to your hosting provider and say "yes, i'll pay more", waiting for them to change the config, and rebooting.

Comment: there is no apache or mysql config to solve this problem?

Comment: if your processes are only using about 250MB then there isn't a problem.  Linux will use any memory unused by programs to cache and buffer the disks, speeding up disk access.  If a process then needs some more RAM, Linux will release the memory for use by programs.  This is perfectly normal and is the way it is supposed to work.

Comment: Multiple `httpd` processes are perfectly normal, since you want to handle several connections at the same time. (For details, we need to know more about your config, for example whether you use worker or prefork mpm.)

Comment: Perhaps [http://www.linuxatemyram.com/](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/) ?